# Naturality of geodesic flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $\texttt{Man}$ be the category of smooth manifolds with local diffeomorphisms as morphisms, and $ \texttt{Bun}$ --- the category of bundles (affine bundles or just fibre bundles, if necessary) and bundle morphisms.
Consider two functors $\texttt{Man} \to \texttt{Bun}$:

- $F: M\mapsto J^1 S^2T^*M$, which sends a manifold to the bundle of 1-jets of symmetric bilinear forms on it.
- $G: M\mapsto TTM$, where $TTM$ is the double tangent bundle.

Is there a characterization of the geodesic flow on $M$ as a *unique* (up to a multiplication by a constant probably) natural transformation  $\eta: F \to G$? It seems necessary to *require* also a homogeneity of degree $2$ with respect to the natural action of $\mathbb R^{>0}$ on $TM$ ("Liouville vector field").

The heuristic why this might be the case is the following. One can choose normal coordinates for any non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form at a point $p$. Thus, by naturality,  $\eta$ on the fiber at $p$ is defined by the value of $\eta$ on the 1-jet of the flat metric. One also needs to require 2-homogeneity of the value of $\eta$ (if we don't do that, the map assigning any section of $J^1 S^2T^*M$ to the Liouville vector field on $TM$ will be natural, but not what we want).
However I cannot see that $\eta$ is uniquely defined for a flat metric (actually *flat metrics*, one for each signature) by 2-homogeneity alone.

Comment: I don't believe $T^*$ is a functor to $Bun$ (see, for example, [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62356/functoriality-of-the-cotangent-bundle)). You should get it as a functor to the dual fibration of vector bundles over smooth manifolds (see [Kock](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01947)).  So it would help me a lot if you could describe what exactly $F$ does to maps.

Comment: @BenMacAdam Thanks for the remark. So far I see two ways to repair the question: 1) either change $TTM$ to $TT^*M$ and ask the same question about the "co-geodesic flow" (both functors are contravariant now) -- one might need to restrict morphisms between manifolds to open embeddings.
2) to change $F$ to the functor $M \mapsto J^1S^2 TM$

Comment: What about a natural transformation for the geodesic flow after multiplying the metric by exp of the scalar curvature? Or after one unit of time with the Ricci flow? If either of those is a valid natural transformation, it’ll be hard to pin down the intended one from pure naturality or other categorical considerations.